# css and divs - parent's attribute for children

Tags: css, html

I have a content-div with style background color set:

```
#content { background-color: #FFF; }
```

The conent div has 3 child-divs like this:

```
#content_right(middle,left) { float: left; width: 500px; }
```

And html code is:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="content_left">...</div>
  <div id="content_middle">...</div>
  <div id="content_right">...</div>
</div>
```

I want the content-background color to be inherited by child-divs but they are not.

It seems the only way to set child div backgrounds is to set them individually for all children.

Question: How can I set bg-color only in the parent content-div so the style will propagate to the child divs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background color is usually treated as **`transparent`**, not **`inherit`**, by default. With **`inherit`**, the background image would be copied to each element and displaced by margins/paddings/etc (has a more obvious effect with background images).

Normally, this wouldn't matter, since the parent would usually become large enough to contain all of the children (so they would show through the parent's background). But, since you're using **`float`** on all children, the actual size of **`#content`** is not actually the size of the child divs combined.

**Floating content can exist outside the bounds of its parent.**

Without any static content of its own, **`#content`** has a height of **0**, while **`content_left/right/middle`** actually exist below it (since they have `...` for content, their height defaults to `line-height`).

To get a better view of what's happening, try adding a height to **`#content`** and background color to the children (or use "Inspect Element" and tag highlighting in Chrome or Firebug):

```
#content { background-color: #FFF; height: 5px; }
#content_right(middle/left) { float: left; width: 500px; background: #ccc; }
```

But, yes, you need to specify the background color in the floating divs rather than their parent.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what exactly you're asking but surely:

```
#content div { background-color: #FFF; }
```

Is an adequate solution?

Answer (score 0):

try declaring your child divs as such in the CSS, like so:

```
#content #content_right(middle,left) { float: left; width: 500px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is **invalid**:

```
#content_right(middle,left)
{ float: left; width: 500px; }
```

The correct would be:

```
#content_right, #content_middle, #content_left
{ float: left; width: 500px; }
```

I guess you've done that just to make the code shorter on your post here at stackoverflow, but I advise you against that. Other users might think that syntax is valid and get confused when noticing that it does not work.

Comment: I know that. I just didn't wanna write much text and content_* has different css-attributes.

Answer (score 0):

### How to propagate parent's css background color to child divs.

Set the child's background-color property to inherit like this:

```
<html>
  <style>
    .header{
        background-color:#EEEEEE;
    }
    .leftChild{
        float:left;
        background-color:inherit;  //<--This says child inherit background color.
    }                           

    .rightChild{
        float:right;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="leftChild">abc</div>
    <div class="rightChild">def</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Only some properties are inherited from the parent automatically.  If, for instance, borders were inherited from the parent, the result would look very messy as all children have borders.

The foreground color is inherited by default, but background-color is not. The reason for this is obvious: in most cases, you’d want the foreground color to be inherited by child elements, but if the parent element had a background image, you wouldn’t want the child elements to have the same image, as their background images probably conflict with their parent’s background image.